# How do I verify from a servlet that the connection was made with two-way SSL?

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, weblogic, x509

I've written a servlet filter to add security to a web application.  In some situations, I want to verify that the connection with the application server was made with two-way SSL (TLS 1.0).  Normally this is done via `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`; however, in my situation, there's a reverse proxy in front of the application server, and this proxy is passing to the application server the client certificate via the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` header.  As such, when I retrieve the aforementioned attribute, I get the client certificate that originally came in the header.  What I want to do is to verify not only the client certificate, but also make sure that the connection between the reverse proxy and the application server is secured with two-way SSL.  Is there a way for me to do this verification from a servlet?  I'm using WebLogic 10.3.4, Java EE 5.  Configuring the WebLogic SSL port to require two-way SSL is not an option, because some other services on that same server require only one-way SSL.

Comment: Are all your app server's connections coming from the reverse proxy?  If so, you *can* require two-way SSL on the app server.  Some connections from the browser to the proxy may not use two-way SSL, but you can ensure that all connections from the proxy to the app server do.

Comment: Well, there's actually two reverse proxies (facing two different vendors): one of the proxies connects via one-way SSL, and the other via two-way SSL.  I've offered the idea of having both proxies connect to the application server using two-way SSL, but the idea hasn't been accepted (yet).  We would rather not manage extra SSL certificates unless we have to.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a client certificate is the same regardless of whether the client is a web browser or your reverse proxy.  Just get the `"javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate"` property and check that it matches your reverse proxy (based on the DN or issuer).

The `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` only comes into play when the app server wants to know what client certificate was presented to the proxy, after verifying that the certificate presented to the app server is the proxy's.

Comment: The problem is that someone could bypass the reverse proxy, take the public key of the reverse proxy's X.509 certificate, then connect to the WebLogic server using one-way SSL and sending the reverse proxy's public key via the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` header.  We've tested this scenario, and it works at fooling the application server.  We want to make sure that these kinds of requests are blocked, while letting legitimate requests go through.

Comment: @vor So you just have to (1) prevent use of the proxy's certificate: in other words disable HTTPS between the proxy and the server, and also (2) disable direct access to the server.

Comment: Disabling SSL is not an option, as we need to have the entire communication path encrypted.

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to see the proxy's certificate in the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` header.  That header tells you who connected *to* the proxy.  The `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` property tells you who's connected to the app server.  Use the `X509Certificate` property to verify that the client connecting to the app server is really the proxy, and then you can trust that the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` it gave you belongs to the user who connected to the proxy.

Comment: @Wyzard, that would be great, but unfortunately, the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` header is missing by the time I call `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`, and the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute contains the client certificate (and not the reverse-proxy certificate).  So I still need a way to verify that two-way SSL was performed between the reverse proxy and the application server.

Comment: So Weblogic is automatically overriding the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` property with the value of the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert`?  Ugh.  See if you can [configure it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss40/configsecurity/clientcert.html) not to lie to your app like that, or at least to do its own verification of the real (proxy's) certificate before replacing it with the proxied user's one.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll get in the original request in your filter using `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` is the certificate as seen by the application server: this will be the reverse proxy's own client certificate, if it's using one.

Depending on your requirements, you can make authorisation-related decisions based on this attribute if you need. You shouldn't need to verify whether you trust the certificate itself, since the authentication should be done by the SSL connector of the application server (configured with an appropriate trust store).

It's likely that most of your applications within the container will expect `getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` to refer to the user's certificate, not the proxy's certificate.

It's not clear in which format you get the values of your `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` additional header, but I'll assume some PEM format.
You should be able to convert this content and place it into the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute in the filter, before it hits the rest of your filters/logic. This should be an array of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` representing the chain of certificates (client-certificate first, followed by issuers). You can make the conversion using a [`CertificateFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) (see examples), or perhaps BouncyCastle's `PEMReader`.

You can verify those certificates there, but I'd say there's little point in doing so. This should really be done within the reverse proxy, when the connection between the user and the proxy is done. If you don't trust the proxy, it could send you any certificate it wants anyway: you won't be able to check that the user has the private key for that certificate from a worker node, only the reverse proxy can do this.

This being said, you can certainly make authorisation decisions using client certificates obtained this way (again, provided you trust the reverse proxy: for this reason, you *must* authenticate the reverse proxy that sends you that information one way or another).

Answer (score -2):

There wouldn't *be* a client certificate unless there was two-way SSL authentication. The existence of the certificate is proof enough.

Comment: The fact is that there are _two_ X.509 certificates we want to verify: the one sent by the client, and the one used by the proxy.  So, once the request reaches the WebLogic server, on a proper request, there will be these two X.509 certificates: the one that the client used in its SSL session with the reverse proxy (being sent by the reverse proxy as an HTTP header), and the one being used by the reverse proxy for the SSL connection between the reverse proxy and the WebLogic server (used in the SSL handshake with the WebLogic server).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @vor23 So you have to look at the certificate to see which it is. Question still doesn't make sense.

Comment: We want to verify that the path between the client and the reverse proxy, and the path between the reverse proxy and the application, are both secured by two-way SSL.  When I call `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`, I only get one certificate chain.  My question is essentially this: how do I verify, from the servlet, that the reverse proxy is both sending me the `WL-Proxy-Client-Cert` header _and_ connecting to me via two-way SSL?

Comment: @vor23 The path between the reverse proxy and the servlet normally isn't secured at all, unless it's a non-LAN path. You can trust that Apache HTTPD will give you the client certificate correctly.